# How to deploy React Django app automatically on AWS EC2 using Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, jenkins-pipeline, devops, continuous-delivery

I am new to **Jenkins**. I have a project that runs Django and React on the same port which is running on AWS EC2 machine. My Database runs on RDS. Now I am trying to implement pipeline and automatic deployment using Jenkins. All the tutorials I was reading or watching suggest using **AWS CodeDeploy** service.

This is my sample **Jenkinsfile** now that tests my React code. As now the main intention is to do automatic code deployment so I am not thinking about testing python here. I just want whatever my code to be deployed on EC2 automatically

```
pipeline {
    agent any 
    stages {
        stage('Install dependency') { 
            steps {
                sh "yarn install"
            }
        }
        stage('Test project') { 
            steps {
                sh "yarn test"
            }
        }
        stage('Build project') { 
            steps {
                sh "yarn build"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know about **AWS CodeDeploy** plugin on Jenkins. But it uses S3 and AWS Code Deploy. What I am really trying to achieve is, Can I do something like this

1. I will build my project in Jenkins and it will send my project automatically to the ec2 machine and make it live.

**OR**

2. Can I connect to my ec2 instance and do the same that we do manually. Like - Login to instance, fetch the code from git, merge it, build it, restart the service